# Wordpress javascript in post

Tags: javascript, wordpress

How do I not accomplish **very simply functionality** which should of been included in the core by NOT RENDERING what is inside of `<code></code>` tags.

```
<code>
<script type="text/javascript"> alert('WHY ARE YOU PARSING THIS'); </script>
</code> 

This is parsed by wordpress.
```

---

ok to parse this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> alert('yea parse this please'); </script>
```

Comment: You may *also* want to check for an answer at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Easiest solution: escape the stuff inside of `<code>`

Comment: @sirko then i get `&ltscript&gt ` which is pretty unreadable

Answer (score 0):

You could apply [esc_html](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html) to the content adding a filter in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter('the_content', function($content){
    return preg_replace_callback('~<code>([\s\S]*?)</code>~', function($matches){
        return sprintf('<code>%s</code>', esc_html($matches[1]));
    }, $content);
});
```